# Gradle obsolete raise an error instead of a warning

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-beta01`, gradle fail with:

> ERROR: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.

I search in the documentation but I don't find how to raise `warning`, not `error`. End of 2019 is not here yet.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me and the problem was solved by commenting on the Fabric plugin in gradle.

If your case is the same but you need to continue using the Fabric, I recommend going back to the to the previous version of the gradle at the project level.

Change the classpath version to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1`.

Comment: The warning is really a warning now with the final version `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'` 